# I need to be able to find the data type of a column in a MS Access table.

Tags: vb.net, types

I need to be able to find the data type of a column in a MS Access table.  I'm using VB 2013 and have tried CheckType and TypeOf methods/functions.
I can test the data that is in one of the rows but that doesn't help me as any given row may have null values in a given column.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the type from the [DataColumn.DataType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.datatype(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

```
For Each dc as DataColumn in DataTable.Columns)
{
    ' dc.DataType.ToString() is the name of the type of data in the column
}
```